# Microsoft Visual Web Developer, All Numbers Missing from Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having a very frustrating problem with Microsoft Visual Web Developer.  I have a very important project I need to work on.  Two days ago, when I opened the project, I noticed that all the numbers except for zero appear as spaces in my files (code files/config files/txt files -- all of them).

If I type a number other than zero, it shows up as spaces.  I can't even see the numbers that I am typing!  All my files have been converted to spaces instead of numbers.  The information is still there because if I copy and paste into another editor (notepad, word, etc), you can see everything perfectly.  Does anyone have a clue how to fix this problem?  I have already uninstalled and reinstalled Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

This is part of what one of my files should look like:

```
<add key="BU_1" value="ACSI" />
<add key="BU_2" value="ESSE" />
<add key="BU_3" value="CorporateSys" />
<add key="BU_4" value="E2EConsumer" />
<add key="BU_5" value="ITO" />
```

This is what it actually looks like:

```
<add key="BU_ " value="ACSI" />
<add key="BU_ " value="ESSE" />
<add key="BU_ " value="CorporateSys" />
<add key="BU_ " value="E EConsumer" />
<add key="BU_ " value="ITO" />
```

Thanks.

---SOLUTION---

Okay, so I changed everything back to "Default" under the settings mentioned by the person who answered this question, but that did not work.  While I was in there, I noticed that the font was on something called "Consolas".  There was no default for the font, so I just flipped it to Courier New, and viola!  It worked!  In case you're wondering, no, I did not change my font to begin with.  I'm not sure what happened

Comment: When you select the code (thus highlighting it) can you see the number? I think it's how it is being displayed (same colour foreground and background) not that it is actually a space.

Comment: @Kate -- No, you could not see the numbers when highlighting.  It looked like plain spaces, highlighted or not.  The only way I could see it was by pasting into a new editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try resetting the Fonts and Colors:
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> select "Use Defaults" for each of the settings. I'm not sure how to set the defaults for all settings in one go.

Comment: See my edited question above -- changing to defaults didn't fix this problem, but editing the selected font that was on that same screen did.  Thanks!